# Using Omniauth with Rails + React - CORS issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redirect, cors, shopify

I am trying to use omniauth for authentication in my rails/react app using the [`shopify`](https://github.com/Shopify/omniauth-shopify-oauth2) strategy.

After sending the user to the omniauth path:

`SessionsController`

```
def authenticate
  redirect_to "/auth/shopify?shop=#{params[:shop]}"
end
```

Omniauth is sending a 302 redirect to my browser:

`Rails Output`

```
(shopify) Setup endpoint detected, running now.
(shopify) Request phase initiated.
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Mar/2018:15:02:40 DST] "GET /auth/shopify?shop=xxx.myshopify.com HTTP/1.1" 302 280
http://localhost:8082/ -> /auth/shopify?shop=xxx.myshopify.com
```

After that happens, a CORS error appears in my browser:

```
Failed to load https://x.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id=x&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fshopify%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=read_products&state=x: 
Redirect from 'https://x.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id=x&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fshopify%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=read_products&state=x' 
to 'https://x.myshopify.com/admin/auth/login' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This causes my fetch request to fail without anything in the error object.

How can I prevent this error?

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to do this ?

Comment: I didn't get around it, I had to write my own auth flow from scratch, which wasn't that hard. It's documented [here](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth)